# Is there a way to narrow typescript overloads with optional parameters?

Tags: typescript, overloading, narrowing

I'm trying to do the following:

```
interface RgbColor {
  r: number;
  g: number;
  b: number;
}

function rgbToHex(r: RgbColor, g?: undefined, b?: undefined): string
function rgbToHex(r: number, g: number, b: number): string
function rgbToHex(r: number|RgbColor, g?: number, b?: number): string {
  if (r instanceof Object) {
    // must be RgbColor
    g = r.g;
    b = r.b;
    r = r.r;
  }

  // A) r was an RgbColor and we've already set r, g, and b to numbers in the if block
  // B) we're meeting the second overload and r, g, and b are all numbers
  // either way we know they are all numbers now

  let rHex = r.toString(16);
  let gHex = g.toString(16); // ERROR: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
  let bHex = b.toString(16); // ERROR: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

  if (rHex.length == 1) rHex = "0" + rHex;
  if (gHex.length == 1) gHex = "0" + gHex;
  if (bHex.length == 1) bHex = "0" + bHex;

  return "#" + rHex + gHex + bHex;
}
```

I'm getting the errors on the lines indicated by `ERROR` comments.

From a javascript perspective the function is fine:

```
function rgbToHex(r , g, b) {
  if (r instanceof Object) {
    g = r.g; 
    b = r.b; 
    r = r.r;
  }

  let rHex = r.toString(16);
  let gHex = g.toString(16);
  let bHex = b.toString(16);

  if (rHex.length == 1) rHex = "0" + rHex;
  if (gHex.length == 1) gHex = "0" + gHex;
  if (bHex.length == 1) bHex = "0" + bHex;

  return "#" + rHex + gHex + bHex;
}

rgbToHex({ r: 120, g: 50, b: 5 }) // "#783205"
rgbToHex(120, 50, 5) // "#783205"
```

My question is how can I **setup the function signatures** such that this just works without having to do any casting and without setting up any redundant variables in the function body. i.e. I want to avoid doing `let gVal: number = g || (r as any).g;`.

The other alternative would be to split this into two function and have one call the other; but I wouldn't do that with javascript, so it seems wrong that I'd have to do that with typescript.

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHMBGBhA9gG1ymQG8AoZZKALmRAFcBbTaAbguXVoebY825MWUdgF8yZGPRAIwwXCCpYAKrgASEAB4AKGmix5CUADScA-LWkATCDFAQrpzBeTXb9qwEpaAZzBRQdElpWXlFKBV1LV1BXhNOWOEnROhvZD8AkCCpGTkFJUxVDR09HmEAHwwcAiJTdBcy6CcGoVTff0DSDmAYZF1kUD84GQhcXoB5TAArCFlPLspKAHol5EZ6P2QWfWqjDkp0ZABeKgA6dHZFreOzzEvF4hOoU5EOcQ4V5ABBeeIAdzgPmQwx2hiIwJAVmQfwgAHIAG4oOD4KAQOBWACe6QgYCodVMwyhmGQYFwdFaUCBoBJAAsUD0toQEABrD6rABC8xhsNRawgOM6YDp2IQCihuERUEI6IhUPi6AJkOucF5yPw5LiPjZyAgwCF0GhcCxMOQzJAuD%20tIgWJVSPw6salLoFoklHwOKoxRuz1JAGUOlltABGABsnnu7tx6C9J3Qpz9AfQwbDrGQnwAoqhUONULRJjNZAMgQAHXA%20HzATD4LGwtx2EAOWGnDiRrYxrbx3D%20zJJ0PhtOrTPZ3PIfOzXHAEtlitVmt1jxN10DXq6Yqnd1ZIXHE5B37tgBEAAZ98gANSerT3BnaaNadcQTc07fIXecA-Hs9vy-dFeYNcb9AtyOHd5j-LQbiPE9zzAzR2A4VEwHoKBFH3ABiKCL00T9byw6DijEIA)

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I spent a couple of hours looking through similar questions but I couldn't find anything that addressed this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more googling, reading of other SO questions, and flicking through the typescript github issues, it looks like this is a yet-to-be-implemented feature within typescript.

The overload narrowing that works outside of a function does not yet apply within a function:

```
// function definition for swapping between number and string types
function foo(bar: string): number // overload 1
function foo(bar: number): string // overload 2
function foo(bar: number | string): number|string 
{ ... }

const a = foo('string');
a.toPrecision(); // TS knows a is a number, so this has no errors

const b = foo(5);
b.toLowerCase(); // TS knows b is a string, so this has no errors

const c = Math.random() < .5 ? a : b; // TS knows c as string | number

// the actual implementation of an overloaded method does not count as 
// one of the possible overloads, so calling foo with a variable of type (string|number)
// is not valid
const d = foo(c); // error on parameter 'c': No overload matches this call.
```

So that's all as expected. But when we try to implement `foo` we see the same exclusionary logic is not applied within the method:

```
function foo(bar: string): number // overload 1
function foo(bar: number): string // overload 2
function foo(bar: number | string): number | string {
  return bar; // this is valid, it clearly should not be
}
```

It looks like the typescript team have not yet made the code-analysis within a function aware of the overloads of that function, it seems like strictly the signature of the implementation is enforced. This is obviously wrong.

QED: Error in tooling. Wait for fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the variables `g` and `b` will always be of type `number | undefined`, they can't be reassigned permanently, without declaring a new variable.

You have 4 options:

1. Use the Non-Null Assertion Operator `!`, meaning instead of writing `g.toString(16)` you need to write `g!.toString(16)`, forcing it to be of type `number`. You could also solve it with a typecast.
2. You can separate it into multiple functions, extract the rgb variables and then return the original `rgbToHex` function.
3. As mentioned in the answer of @Oblosys you can use a union type.
4. You could create a new object at the top of the function, where you fill a new `RgbColor` object.

Comment: "The problem is, the variables g and b will always be of type number | undefined, they can't be reassigned permanently, without declaring a new variable."  

This is why the question is about overload narrowing, if TS is able to figure out that `r` is of shape `RgbColor` within the if block, then the rest of the logic should follow as in the few lines of comments following the if block.

I didn't know about the Non-Null Assertion Operator, upvote for that. I'm hoping there's something else I don't know about that answers the question as specified.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try implementing the following.

```
function f(a: T, b: S);
function f(a: U, b: S, c: V);

function f(a: T | U, b: S, c?: V) { ... }
```

After a lot of unhelpful errors and testing around, I managed to write the following for a program that makes a custom log message with some parameters.

```
type LogActionWithoutBuff = 'connect' | 'disconnect';
type LogActionWithBuff = 'receive' | 'send';
type LogAction = LogActionWithBuff | LogActionWithoutBuff;

function formatLog(action: LogActionWithoutBuff, host: string): string;
function formatLog(action: LogActionWithBuff, host: string, buff: Buffer): string;

function formatLog(action: LogAction, host: string, buff?: Buffer): string { ... }
```

I tried multiple times to do the same exact thing (not referencing buff at all), but it only worked right now. I can't figure out why, maybe a problem with the compiler.